# SemaphoreSlim with dynamic maxCount

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, .net-4.5

I'm facing a problem where I need to limit the number of calls to another web server. It will vary because the server is shared and maybe it could have more or less capacity.

I was thinking about using SemaphoreSlim class, but there's no public property to change the max count.

Should I wrap my SemaphoreSlim class in another class that will handle the max count? Is there any better approach?

EDIT:

Here's what I'm trying:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Semaphore
{
class Program
{
    static SemaphoreSlim _sem = new SemaphoreSlim(10,10000);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int max = 15;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            new Thread(Enter).Start(new int[] { i, max});
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        max = 11;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            new Thread(Enter).Start(new int[] { i, max });
        }
    }

    static void Enter(object param)
    {
        int[] arr = (int[])param;
        int id = arr[0];
        int max = arr[1];

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_sem.CurrentCount);

            if (_sem.CurrentCount <= max)
                _sem.Release(1);
            else
            {
                _sem.Wait(1000);

                Console.WriteLine(id + " wants to enter");

                Thread.Sleep((1000 * id) / 2); // can be here at

                Console.WriteLine(id + " is in!"); // Only three threads

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("opps ", id);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally            
        {
            _sem.Release();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Questions:

1-_sem.Wait(1000) should cancel the execution of threads that will execute for more than 1000ms, wasn't it?

2-Did I got the idea of using Release / Wait?

Answer (score 27):

You can't change the max count, but you can create a `SemaphoreSlim` that has a very high maximum count, and reserve some of them. See [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So let's say that the *absolute maximum* number of concurrent calls is 100, but initially you want it to be 25. You initialize your semaphore:

```
SemaphoreSlim sem = new SemaphoreSlim(25, 100);
```

So 25 is the number of requests that can be serviced concurrently. You have reserved the other 75.

If you then want to increase the number allowed, just call [Release(num)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289587%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you called `Release(10)`, then the number would go to 35.

Now, if you want to reduce the number of available requests, you have to call `WaitOne` multiple times. For example, if you want to remove 10 from the available count:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    sem.WaitOne();
}
```

This has the potential of blocking until other clients release the semaphore. That is, if you allow 35 concurrent requests and you want to reduce it to 25, but there are already 35 clients with active requests, that `WaitOne` will block until a client calls `Release`, and the loop won't terminate until 10 clients release.

Comment: This could help, but I need something flexible. Lets say, max 1000 concurrent, but after some hours, the max should be 600 or 1200. I believe that SemaphoreSlim won't give me this flexible. =(

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio: Did you even read the answer? Set the second parameter to the *maximum you will ever allow*. Then you can use `Release` and `WaitOne` as described to adjust the number that are available.

Comment: Could you take a look at my sample code and help me?

Comment: @jim-mischel Can you think of a way we could ensure the number of semaphore slots does not go below a given minimum? I want to avoid reducing the number of slots to zero and therefore preventing any of my tasks to proceed. would something like this be reliable: `if (sem.CurrentCount > myMinNumberOfSlots) sem.Wait();`

Comment: @jim-mischel I did some testing and realized that we can rule out `CurrentCount` for the purpose of determining the number of slots. This property indicates the number of slots currently *available* and its value goes up or down with every call to `Release` or `Wait`.

Comment: You can use a while to consume requests until it drops you your required level: while(semLock.CurrentCount > 1)
                        {
                            await semLock.WaitAsync();
                        }

Answer (score 6):

1. Get a semaphore.
2. Set the capacity to something quite a bit higher than you need it to be.
3. Set the initial capacity to what you want your *actual* maximum capacity to be.
4. Give out the semaphore to others to use.

At this point you can then wait on the semaphore however much you want (without a corresponding release call) to lower the capacity.  You can release the semaphore a number of times (without a corresponding wait call) to increase the effective capacity.

If this is something you're doing enough of, you can potentially create your own semaphore class that composes a `SemaphoreSlim` and encapsulates this logic.  This composition will also be essential if you have code that already releases a semaphore without first waiting on it; with your own class you could ensure that such releases are no-ops.  (That said, you should avoid putting yourself in that position to begin with, really.)

Comment: Or just call the constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270891(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Even with my own class that encapsulates SemaphoreSlim, I need flexibility to switch the max concurrent calls up or down. i.e start with 1000, alter to 600 and after some time to 1700.

Comment: @JimMischel Sure, although if you want to actually be able to change the proper maximum you really would need to compose it in another type, so that you could ensure that releasing it when it's already at the maximum without first increasing the maximum becomes a noop (or an exception).

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Yes, and what's the problem with that?  You can have a `SetMaxium` method that either waits or releases as appropriate based on the difference between the current and desired maximum.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I was just saying that your step 3 could be eliminated if you used that constructor in step 2. As for the rest of your answer (and your comment), I agree completely. Without encapsulation, this kind of thing can be pretty dangerous.

Comment: @Servy I've posted my code, could you take a look please?

Comment: Guys what if I have multiple servers running the same application and I want one message to be processed only once at a time , now I am running my consumer on multiple servers but I am getting duplicate procession for the same message , used semaphore only to make sure once message processed once on the same multicore server but for multiple servers what could we do?

Comment: @Khalid use a distributed lock like redis distributed locks - ref: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-distributed-lock-with-redis-in-net-core/

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved this situation: I created a custom semaphore slim class that allows me to increase and decrease the number of slots. This class also allows me to set a maximum number of slots so I never exceed a "reasonable" number and also to set a minimum number of slots so I don't go below a "reasonable" threshold.

```
using Picton.Messaging.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Picton.Messaging.Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An improvement over System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim that allows you to dynamically increase and
    /// decrease the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently.
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim" />
    public class SemaphoreSlimDynamic : SemaphoreSlim
    {
        #region FIELDS

        private static readonly ILog _logger = LogProvider.GetLogger(typeof(SemaphoreSlimDynamic));
        private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;

        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the minimum number of slots.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The minimum slots count.
        /// </value>
        public int MinimumSlotsCount { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of slots currently available.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The available slots count.
        /// </value>
        public int AvailableSlotsCount { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the maximum number of slots.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The maximum slots count.
        /// </value>
        public int MaximumSlotsCount { get; private set; }

        #endregion

        #region CONSTRUCTOR

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SemaphoreSlimDynamic"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minCount">The minimum number of slots.</param>
        /// <param name="initialCount">The initial number of slots.</param>
        /// <param name="maxCount">The maximum number of slots.</param>
        public SemaphoreSlimDynamic(int minCount, int initialCount, int maxCount)
            : base(initialCount, maxCount)
        {
            _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);

            this.MinimumSlotsCount = minCount;
            this.AvailableSlotsCount = initialCount;
            this.MaximumSlotsCount = maxCount;
        }

        #endregion

        #region PUBLIC METHODS

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to increase the number of slots
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="millisecondsTimeout">The timeout in milliseconds.</param>
        /// <param name="increaseCount">The number of slots to add</param>
        /// <returns>true if the attempt was successfully; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public bool TryIncrease(int millisecondsTimeout = 500, int increaseCount = 1)
        {
            return TryIncrease(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecondsTimeout), increaseCount);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to increase the number of slots
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
        /// <param name="increaseCount">The number of slots to add</param>
        /// <returns>true if the attempt was successfully; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public bool TryIncrease(TimeSpan timeout, int increaseCount = 1)
        {
            if (increaseCount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(increaseCount));
            else if (increaseCount == 0) return false;

            var increased = false;

            try
            {
                if (this.AvailableSlotsCount < this.MaximumSlotsCount)
                {
                    var lockAcquired = _lock.TryEnterWriteLock(timeout);
                    if (lockAcquired)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < increaseCount; i++)
                        {
                            if (this.AvailableSlotsCount < this.MaximumSlotsCount)
                            {
                                Release();
                                this.AvailableSlotsCount++;
                                increased = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (increased) _logger.Trace($"Semaphore slots increased: {this.AvailableSlotsCount}");

                        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SemaphoreFullException)
            {
                // An exception is thrown if we attempt to exceed the max number of concurrent tasks
                // It's safe to ignore this exception
            }

            return increased;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to decrease the number of slots
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="millisecondsTimeout">The timeout in milliseconds.</param>
        /// <param name="decreaseCount">The number of slots to add</param>
        /// <returns>true if the attempt was successfully; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public bool TryDecrease(int millisecondsTimeout = 500, int decreaseCount = 1)
        {
            return TryDecrease(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisecondsTimeout), decreaseCount);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to decrease the number of slots
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timeout">The timeout.</param>
        /// <param name="decreaseCount">The number of slots to add</param>
        /// <returns>true if the attempt was successfully; otherwise, false.</returns>
        public bool TryDecrease(TimeSpan timeout, int decreaseCount = 1)
        {
            if (decreaseCount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(decreaseCount));
            else if (decreaseCount == 0) return false;

            var decreased = false;

            if (this.AvailableSlotsCount > this.MinimumSlotsCount)
            {
                var lockAcquired = _lock.TryEnterWriteLock(timeout);
                if (lockAcquired)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < decreaseCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (this.AvailableSlotsCount > this.MinimumSlotsCount)
                        {
                            if (Wait(timeout))
                            {
                                this.AvailableSlotsCount--;
                                decreased = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (decreased) _logger.Trace($"Semaphore slots decreased: {this.AvailableSlotsCount}");

                    _lock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            }

            return decreased;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I could solve my problem lookin on mono project.

```
// SemaphoreSlim.cs
//
// Copyright (c) 2008 Jérémie "Garuma" Laval
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.
//
//

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace System.Threading
{
    public class SemaphoreSlimCustom : IDisposable
    {
        const int spinCount = 10;
        const int deepSleepTime = 20;
        private object _sync = new object();


        int maxCount;
        int currCount;
        bool isDisposed;

        public int MaxCount
        {
            get { lock (_sync) { return maxCount; } }
            set
            {
                lock (_sync)
                {
                    maxCount = value;
                }
            }
        }

        EventWaitHandle handle;

        public SemaphoreSlimCustom (int initialCount) : this (initialCount, int.MaxValue)
        {
        }

        public SemaphoreSlimCustom (int initialCount, int maxCount)
        {
            if (initialCount < 0 || initialCount > maxCount || maxCount < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("The initialCount  argument is negative, initialCount is greater than maxCount, or maxCount is not positive.");

            this.maxCount = maxCount;
            this.currCount = initialCount;
            this.handle = new ManualResetEvent (initialCount > 0);
        }

        public void Dispose ()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose (bool disposing)
        {
            isDisposed = true;
        }

        void CheckState ()
        {
            if (isDisposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException ("The SemaphoreSlim has been disposed.");
        }

        public int CurrentCount {
            get {
                return currCount;
            }
        }

        public int Release ()
        {
            return Release(1);
        }

        public int Release (int releaseCount)
        {
            CheckState ();
            if (releaseCount < 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("releaseCount", "releaseCount is less than 1");

            // As we have to take care of the max limit we resort to CAS
            int oldValue, newValue;
            do {
                oldValue = currCount;
                newValue = (currCount + releaseCount);
                newValue = newValue > maxCount ? maxCount : newValue;
            } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange (ref currCount, newValue, oldValue) != oldValue);

            handle.Set ();

            return oldValue;
        }

        public void Wait ()
        {
            Wait (CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public bool Wait (TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            return Wait ((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public bool Wait (int millisecondsTimeout)
        {
            return Wait (millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public void Wait (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Wait (-1, cancellationToken);
        }

        public bool Wait (TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            CheckState();
            return Wait ((int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds, cancellationToken);
        }

        public bool Wait (int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            CheckState ();
            if (millisecondsTimeout < -1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("millisecondsTimeout",
                                                       "millisecondsTimeout is a negative number other than -1");

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Func<bool> stopCondition = () => millisecondsTimeout >= 0 && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > millisecondsTimeout;

            do {
                bool shouldWait;
                int result;

                do {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();
                    if (stopCondition ())
                        return false;

                    shouldWait = true;
                    result = currCount;

                    if (result > 0)
                        shouldWait = false;
                    else
                        break;
                } while (Interlocked.CompareExchange (ref currCount, result - 1, result) != result);

                if (!shouldWait) {
                    if (result == 1)
                        handle.Reset ();
                    break;
                }

                SpinWait wait = new SpinWait ();

                while (Thread.VolatileRead (ref currCount) <= 0) {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();
                    if (stopCondition ())
                        return false;

                    if (wait.Count > spinCount) {
                        int diff = millisecondsTimeout - (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                        int timeout = millisecondsTimeout < 0 ? deepSleepTime :


                            Math.Min (Math.Max (diff, 1), deepSleepTime);
                        handle.WaitOne (timeout);
                    } else
                        wait.SpinOnce ();
                }
            } while (true);

            return true;
        }

        public WaitHandle AvailableWaitHandle {
            get {
                return handle;
            }
        }

        public Task WaitAsync ()
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Wait ());
        }

        public Task WaitAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Wait (cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        }

        public Task<bool> WaitAsync (int millisecondsTimeout)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Wait (millisecondsTimeout));
        }

        public Task<bool> WaitAsync (TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Wait (timeout));
        }

        public Task<bool> WaitAsync (int millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Wait (millisecondsTimeout, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        }

        public Task<bool> WaitAsync (TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() => Wait (timeout, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated .Net Core 5 answer:

Let's say I want a lock with a maximum of 10 requests, but most of the time I only want 1.

```
private readonly static SemaphoreSlim semLock = new(1, 10);
```

Now when I want to release some resources I can do:

```
semLock.Release(Math.Min(9, requiredAmount));
```

note that 9 is one less than 10 as we already have one release initially.

Once I want to restrict the available resources again I can call:

```
while(semLock.CurrentCount > 1)
{
    await semLock.WaitAsync();
}
```

which will await bringing it back down to 1

Comment: Checking `CurrentCount` will show wrong value. if `semLock` is under use then it can have already `CurrentCount  == 0` but second after will go back to 10.
Correct solution need to have separate counter to check how many times `WaitAsync` on given lock.