# Increase/Decrease number of available slots in SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

**EDIT**: *my question, as originally phrased, implied that SemaphoreSlim creates and destroys threads which is not accurate. Re-phrasing to use "slots" instead of "threads", I believe this is more accurate.*

I use the `SemaphoreSlim` class to control the rate I access a given resource and it works great. However, I'm struggling how I can dynamically increase and decrease the number of slots that are available.

Ideally, the SemaphoreSlim would have `Increase()` and `Decrease()` methods with the following characteristics:

- `Increase()` increases the max number of slots available by 1
- `Decrease()` decreases the max number of slots availble by 1
- These methods do not wait, they return immediately
- When the configurable max number of slots is reached, subsequent calls to `Increase()` are equivalent to noop (no exception is thrown)
- When the configurable min number of slots is reached, subsequent calls to `Decrease()` are equivalent to noop (no exception is thrown)
- When `Decrease()` is invoked and all slots are in use, the max number of slots is decreased when a slots is released

Is there a .NET construct that allows something like this?

Comment: Semaphores do not create or destroy threads.  They support post and wait.  Do you mean a runtime-configurable limit on the number of threads that have access to some single resource?

Comment: It is called "threadpool".  You'd be unwise not to use the existing one, but you can certainly shop for alternatives.  Include the word "smart" or "alternative" in your google query.

Comment: Ok I think I didn't use the correct vocabulary. I didn't mean to imply that SemaphoreSlim reserved a certain number of threads (although I just re-read my question and that's EXACTLY what I said!). I meant to say that SemaphoreSlim acts as a "gatekeeper" and allows restricting how many processes access a certain resource. I want to be able to increase/decrease the number of "gates" or maybe they are called "slots" (hopefully that's the right terminology).

Comment: This answer to a similar question sounds promising (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24067362) although there is no guard against lowering the number of slots below a determined min value.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in a comment, a semaphore is does neither create nor destroy a thread. What you are describing and probably searching for is the functionality of the [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) class. It has some methods like [`SetMinThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx), [`SetMaxThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx), [`QueueUserWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) and will pretty sure do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following extension method to increase the number of slots (up to the configured maximum):

```
public static void Increase(this SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
  try
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
  catch
  {
    // An exception is thrown if we attempt to exceed the max number of concurrent tasks
    // It's safe to ignore this exception
  }
}
```

This extension method can be used like so:

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2, 5);  // two slot are initially available and the max is 5 slots
semaphore.Increase();  // three slots are now available
semaphore.Increase();  // four slots are now available
semaphore.Increase();  // five slots are now available
semaphore.Increase();  // we are attempting to exceed the max; an exception is thrown but it's caught and ignored. The number of available slots remains five
```

Now I need to figure out how to implement the "Decrease()" method. Any suggestion?