# Dynamic limitation of concurrent tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there a type for this example, such as TaskScheduler or some other type with which I could dynamically change the number of tasks being executed in parallel? I just need a yes or no answer, if yes, which one. It is necessary only for the example below.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task[] tasks = new Task[100000]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(10000));
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I just need a yes or no answer, if yes, which one."* -- That's not how "yes or no" answers work. "Yes or no" means that a yes or no alone is a sufficient answer.

Comment: Yes, look at Parallel.ForEachAsync.

Comment: Can you please explain more - what and why are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if there is a certain type object for this example with the help of which I can dynamically control the number of simultaneously executed tasks. I thought perhaps TaskScheduler would do. For example, from another thread, I set a certain property and now tasks are executed 10 pieces, 20 pieces a second later, 5 pieces a second later. For the methods of the parallel class, there are ParallelOptions. But the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property is only checked on initialization once. It can be changed dynamically, but the number of tasks will remain the same.

Comment: _" tasks are performed 10 times a second, 20 times a second, 5 seconds later."_ - sounds a little bit suspicious to me. AFAIK If task is already running it will not be stopped ( though for IO-bound ones - they would not be resumed after IO is complete if there are no available threads)

Comment: Is this helpful? [SemaphoreSlim with dynamic maxCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067200/semaphoreslim-with-dynamic-maxcount)

Answer (score 0):

`Task` run on the thread pool, to some extent you can leverage [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=net-6.0) (note that you cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer):

```cs
int counter = 0;
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(32, 32);
Task[] tasks = new Task[1000]; 

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    if (i == 500)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(16, 16);
    }
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        Console.WriteLine($"Concurrently running {Volatile.Read(ref counter)}"); // you will see change in maximum number of concurrent task running
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
       
        Console.WriteLine($"Concurrently end {Volatile.Read(ref counter)}");
    });
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Though in general it is not recommended to change thread pool size:

> Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse effect on code libraries you use.
> Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems. If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching overhead becomes a significant factor.

Another option is to adapt `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-6.0#examples) and use `TaskFactory` to instantiate new tasks.

Comment: Thank you. I did the code, and still the CPU is 100% busy for all 32 threads. Code: using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2, 2);

            Task[] tasks = new Task[10000];

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => { int i = 0; while (i<10000000) { i++; } } );
            }
            
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        }
    }
}

Comment: @user18243635 from the answer - _"note that you cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer"_. I highly doubt that your computer has only 2 processors.

Comment: My computer has one processor, 16 cores and 32 threads. What then generally gives this decision? I need to make from 32 tasks, for example, 5 tasks, then 2 tasks, then 10 tasks.

Comment: @user18243635 1) check out the link in the answer (the one for `SetMaxThreads`). "Processors" in this context mean something different - check out value for `Environment.ProcessorCount`. 2) look into implementation of the linked `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` (and adjust it to have number of max tasks to be modifiable) or use Theodor's suggestion from comments to the question